# How do I set an exposed date filter to allow any value, empty or not empty?

Tags: 7, views

It seems that most view field filters allow the setting 'any', or leaving it empty, to basically disable the filter. I don't see a way in a date field to do the same. 
I have a date with selectboxes for year, month, and day; exposing the operator gives a number of options, including 'is empty' or 'is not empty' but I can't choose 'any'.

How do I set an exposed date filter to allow any value, empty or not empty?